# One Tween object on multiple objects with different animations

Tags: tween, gsap

Using GSAP, I want to create one `TweenLite` or `TweenMax` object which acts different animations (intended to play in parallel) on multiple different objects.

**How can this be done?** I have only seen `allTo` which applies same animation on an array of multiple objects.

It is important to get one tween as I need to pass it to ScrollMagic.

I figured I can use `TimelineLite` or `TimelineMax` to do this too, since that's OK with ScrollMagic.

```
var timeline=new TimelineMax();
timeline.to(object1, duration, animation1, 0);
timeline.to(object2, duration, animation2, 0);
timeline.to(object3, duration, animation3, 0);
```

However, is it possible purely using `TweenLite` or `TweenMax`? Or the timeline is the only way to go?

Comment: If you intend to do different animations on multiple elements then yes, **TimelineMax** is the best option. And I believe `ScrollMagic` can take `TimelineMax` and treat it as one single tween based on the assumption that you are going to be using its `setTween` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to just use `TweenMax` and not `TimelineMax`.. then you could just use `method chaining`, and `chain` your tweens using `TweenMax`

Using `TimelineMax` would be give you greater control.

You could also chain with the `TimelineMax` constructor:

```
 var timeline = new TimelineMax().to(object1, duration, animation1, 0)
                                 .to(object2, duration, animation2, 0)
                                 .to(object3, duration, animation3, 0);
```

Or just do like you were doing, but with chaining:

```
 var timeline = new TimelineMax();
 timeline.to(object1, duration, animation1, 0)
         .to(object2, duration, animation2, 0)
         .to(object3, duration, animation3, 0);
```

See `TweenMax` docs for more information: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/

Comment: Although you can chain `TweenMax` (or Lite), the `.to` method in `TweenMax` is [a **static** method](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to/). Hence the `tweens` variable will just have the **last** call's tween object (the other animations will play, but won't be controllable). There is no *true* chaining happening, and the code is *misleading*. In `TimelineMax` (or Lite), the `.to` method is [**non-static**](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/to/), so you are in fact doing a *true* chaining.

Comment: Also, I don't see the point in your last code block. If I already assigned it to `var timeline`, why re-assign it to another `var tl`? What advantage does it provide? I can just use `timeline` variable in subsequent code.

Comment: its just another way to assign your timeline to a variable.. you can see that in practice here when i assign many timelines to multiple elements. Storing my timeline in a variable and then assign that variable to another var associated with each DOM element .. see this example http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/KdYqWo

Comment: I changed line 22 to `el.animation = tl;` and removed the assignment `var t = tl` (replaced it with just `tl`). The page still works the same. Both `var tl` and `var t` are actually pointing to the same `TimelineMax` object. It doesn't seem to offer any advantage to assign the same object to two different variables. see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKyWbG **PS:** `TweenMax` chaining in your answer is misleading. You should make a note of it and strike it out.

Comment: Sorry about that, codepen sometimes parses javascript wrong due to their infinite loop check, which can cause it to be buggy. When i originally made that code example, codepen wasnt allowing it, even though it worked on my remote testing server.